# Is it normal for you to see :root in your inspect page when using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-variables

[image]

Hi, I'm just wondering if it's okay to see this when you inspect a website? I'm using Bootstrap 4 on a project and this bothers me because it looks unprofressional when you look at it.

If it does look unprofessional, how can I hide it in the inspect page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. Bootstrap utilizes CSS variables which use `:root`:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#css-variables

I have no idea why you'd think it looks unprofessional. The appearance of the browser inspector doesn't effect anything.

Comment: I see but when I try to look at other Bootstrap 4 made websites things like :root don't show on theirs? Sorry, I'm just bothered because it looks like I used bootstrap 100% in my project.

Comment: It will show in any site that uses Bootstrap 4. Again, I don't understand your concern with it. If you're worried about it, don't use Bootstrap.